# Android - is there a way to create discounts for users?

Tags: android

As an Android developer, I have a paid app, but I can not figure out how to create a discount for an app. Is there a way to do that?

For example, I want to give the app to my friends for free, but I can not figure out how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, in android you have to make a free version if you want to give it out freely to testers/friends

Comment: Still, I really wish Google would allow us to implement discount codes or some such.  E.g. to give free copies to reviewers.  Also, there's a 3rd-party app store (I think it was mobihand) that went out of business, orphaning all the customers who bought my app via them.  I really wish I had a handy way to write to all those customers and say "sorry they went out of business; here's a code to let you download a replacement copy for free."